# ios sdk stop multitouch functionality

Tags: ios, xcode, multi-touch, ibaction

I have multiple buttons, if user touches 2 or more buttons and releases simultaneously, I want to give the action of just one button.

How can I do that.
Thanks in advance for your help..

Answer (score 2):

Set `exclusiveTouch` property for all buttons to `yes`. If that is not working, you might have to disable all other buttons when the user is tapping on a particular button and enable it once that particular action is completed.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting your view's `multipleTouchEnabled` property to `NO`.